# Ext JS 5 - Check gridview if it is empty?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I want to check if my grid view is empty or not? Here's what i got so far:

```
var mygrid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mygridID')[0];
//Now i need to check the grid if they have values or not. If it is empty, i want to return a string that says "". Help?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the number of records in the store, that is connected with the GridView:

```
if (!mygrid.getStore().getCount()) {
    return 'empty';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other possible solutions are..

**Solution 1**

```
if(Ext.isEmpty(mygrid.getStore())){
     //Store is empty
} else{
     //Store is not empty
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
if(!mygrid.getStore().getTotalCount()>0){
     //Store is empty
} else{
     //Store is not empty
}
```